# Assume that ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$. Show that if there is no $3$-chain in our sequence, then ${a}_{3}$ must be less than ${a}_{1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Define a $3$-chain to be a (not necessarily contiguous) subsequence
of three integers, which is either monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing. We
will show here that any sequence of five distinct integers will contain a 3-chain. Write
the sequence as ${a}_{1},{a}_{2},{a}_{3},{a}_{4},{a}_{5}$. Note that a monotonically increasing sequences is one in which each term is greater than or equal to the previous term. Similarly, a monotonically
decreasing sequence is one in which each term is less than or equal to the previous term.
Lastly, a subsequence is a sequence derived from the original sequence by deleting some
elements without changing the location of the remaining elements. [Source](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_042JF10_assn02.pdf)

(a) [$4$ pts] Assume that ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$. Show that if there is no $3$-chain in our sequence, then ${a}_{3}$ must be less than ${a}_{1}$. (Hint: consider ${a}_{4}$!)

The proof I wrote up:

Theorem: if there is no 3-chain in our sequence, then ${a}_{3}$ must be less than ${a}_{1}$

Proof: We use proof by contradition

1) Let's assume that if there is no 3-chain sequence, then ${ a }_{ 3 }>{ a }_{ 1 }$

2) This gives rise to two possible cases:

Case 1.${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }<{ a }_{ 3 }$

Case 2. ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$

3) Case 1: let's consider all the possibilities when we introduce ${a}_{4}$

1. ${ a }_{ 4 }<{ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }<{ a }_{ 3 }$
2. ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 4 }<{ a }_{ 2 }<{ a }_{ 3 }$
3. ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }<{ a }_{ 4 }<{ a }_{ 3 }$
4. ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 4 }$

We can see that all of the combinations lead to a 3-chain, so our first case can be disregarded.

4) Case 2. let's consider all the possibilities when we introduce ${a}_{4}$

1. ${ a }_{ 4 }<{ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$
2. ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 4 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$
3. ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 4 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$
4. ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 2 }<{ a }_{ 4 }$

We can see that all of the combinations give a 3-chain:

${ a }_{ 4 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$

${ a }_{ 4 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$

${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 4 }$

${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }<{ a }_{ 4 }$

so our second case can be disregarded.

5) So, our original assumption, that if there is no 3-chain sequence, then
 ${ a }_{ 3 }>{ a }_{ 1 }$, was wrong. This leads us to a contradiction.

Q.E.D.

Please let me know where I made mistakes, and what I need to do to fix them. I am not well-versed in proof writing, so I would like to use this opportunity to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Your argument for Case 1 is way too complicated. In Case 1 there is no need to introduce $a_4.$

Comment: @bof I realized that after I wrote up all the possibilities. Is it wrong or just makes the proof less elegant? 

How is the rest of the proof?

Comment: The negation of "if A then B" is not "if A then not-B", it is "A and not-B". So your "Let's assume" statement should not be an "if-then" statement, it should be "there's no 3-chain **and** $a_3\ge a_1.$

Comment: @bof So, $¬(p\rightarrow q)\leftrightarrow (p\wedge ¬q)$. Why does it become ${ a }_{ 3 }\ge { a }_{ 1 }$ rather than ${ a }_{ 3 }>{ a }_{ 1 }$? I don't understand how the negation of  $<$ turns into $\ge$

Edit: Fixed a few errors I made when typing.

Comment: @bof How do I fix my proof, considering that the ${ a }_{ i }$ can be "or equal" as you pointed out? I also cannot see how I can simplify Case $2$.

Comment: Sorry, you were right. I just noticed that the problem says "sequence of five **distinct** integers". The "or equal" is because they are giving the definition of "monotonically increasing sequence" **in general**, not just for this particular exercise.

Comment: In Case 2 you only need two subcases. If $a_4\lt a_3$ then consider the sequence $a_4\lt a_3\lt a_2;$ if $a_3\lt a_4$ then consider $a_1\lt a_3\lt a_4.$

Comment: @bof I still don't understand why you only need two subcases for case 2. The first two subcases are the same, but subcase 3 and subcase 4 are different. It seems that you haven't considered the subcase 4, ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 2 }<{ a }_{ 4 }$, where we get the 3-chain ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }<{ a }_{ 4 }$.

Comment: Why do you have to use the $3$-chain $a_1\lt a_2\lt a_4$? Why can't you use the $3$-chain $a_1\lt a_3\lt a_4$ in both subcase 3 and subcase 4?

Comment: Oh!!! I see it now! A lightbulb just went off in my head thanks to you. To answer your question: because by the definition of a 3-chain and the definition of a subsequence, we can take the 3-chain ${ a }_{ 1 },{ a }_{ 3 },{ a }_{ 4 }$ from subcase 4, and that is equivalent to the 3-chain we got in subcase 3. 

Can I post the edited proof as an answer below? I would appreciate it if you could go over it and give the final say.

Comment: @bof In addition, feel free to formulate all the advice and help you gave me in these comments into an answer below. I will accept it and +1.

Comment: You can certainly post your edited proof as an answer, and maybe someone will check it for you. I don't think I will do that myself, because it's past my bedtime and I'm tired.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem: if there is no 3-chain in our sequence, then ${a}_{3}$ must be less than ${a}_{1}$

Proof: We use proof by contradition

1) Let's assume that there is no 3-chain sequence and ${ a }_{ 3 }\ge{ a }_{ 1 }$

2) This gives rise to two possible cases:

Case 1: ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }<{ a }_{ 3 }$

Case 2: ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$

3) Case 1: this case will always form a 3-chain no matter where we introduce ${ a }_{ 4 }$. Therefore, we can disregard this case without deeper case analysis.

4) Case 2: let's consider the two sub-cases in which we introduce ${a}_{4}$:

Sub-case 1: $a_4\lt a_3$

Sub-case 2: $a_3\lt a_4$

1. ${ a }_{ 4 }<{ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$
2. ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 2 }<{ a }_{ 4 }$

We can see that both of these cases give a 3-chain:

${ a }_{ 4 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$

${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 4 }$

so our second case can be disregarded.

5) So, our original assumption, there is no 3-chain sequence and
 ${ a }_{ 3 }\ge{ a }_{ 1 }$, was wrong. This leads us to a contradiction.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Did you manage to work through all assignments of that discrete mathematics course?

Comment: @Max For the most part. Why?

Comment: More of interest, because I was looking up solutions for these things, as I'm also following the course and I mostly find your questions/answers when searching for them.